# POSTGRES: Levenshtein distance with an array of bigint

Tags: arrays, postgresql, levenshtein-distance

I know Postgres has a levenshtein distance function you can call on strings. The problem I have is that I need to call it on an array of bigints and I'm not sure how to do that, or if it's even possible.

Take this table for example:

```
asn | as_path
1   | {123, 4567, 8910}
2   | {123, 234, 456, 8910}
```

Is there any way I could get the levenshtein distance between the as_paths of the first and second row, treating each bigint as a whole unit that cannot be split?

If it helps, these Arrays never are larger than 15 across (>90% of the time they are 4 or less), and that we know in advance every single number that exists in the as_path column (of which there are about 80k).

EDIT:
I suppose that theoretically, if you know array length is never longer than 15, you could have, for every comparison, a lookup in a table to map each number to a letter. I was just wondering if there was a more efficient way to do this.

Comment: It is probably best to implement the algorithm yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the default implementation is faster than anything I could come up with, so I don't want to implement my own. I think actually I've figured out the solution. We know in advance that there are only 80k numbers, and we know these numbers in advance.

1. Create a mapping of each possible number in any given as_path to an id of 1, 2...80k
2. Every time you do a levenshtein compare, for each number, lookup the given number mapping, and from the id value, call chr(id). This will turn the number into a unicode character.
3. Concatenate all the unicode characters together

This won't work if you don't know all the numbers in advance, nor will it work if you have more numbers than you have unicode characters.

I can't post the code for this now, I'll have to do it later.